# How to send LinkedList from Red5(Java) to Flex(AS3)?

Tags: apache-flex, linked-list, send, red5

I have a linked list of data in Red5server that updating every 8 second. I want to send this linked list to Flex.
is it possible using shared object? or any other solution?
I'll appreciate the details, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think netconnection and sharedobject are the answer. try start google with it